# How to detect whether Node installed when node is not available in Environment

Tags: node.js, macos, shell

I am trying to package an app that I have built for the Mac OS using the [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) software. For the app to install, there are pre-requisites which should be already installed on the system, one of which is node. I am checking for the pre requisites by [Defining Requirement](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/Distribution_Installation_Type.html#5) based on the result of an external shell script.

Basically, the packager software runs the specified external script and if the script returns a given value it proceeds else it throws an error.

I have written the following script to detect whether node is installed

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Checking PreReq Node" 

node --version | grep "v" &> /dev/null 
if [ $? == 0 ]; then 
 echo "Node Installed"
 exit 0;
else 
 echo "Node not installed"
 exit 1;
fi
```

This works as expected when I run it in the shell, but when running within the context of the installer, node is not available in the environment so it fails. If I change the script to use the full path of node it works

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Checking PreReq Node" 

/usr/local/bin/node --version | grep "v" &> /dev/null 
if [ $? == 0 ]; then 
 echo "Node Installed"
 exit 0;
else 
 echo "Node not installed"
 exit 1;
fi
```

However, node may be installed in a different location on a different system.

How can I check whether node is installed on a system without actually running node?

Comment: Try `which node`, it returns the path of the app.

Comment: If node is not available in the environment, which node also fails.

Comment: Yeah, of course.  A failure on "which node" gives you your answer that node is NOT in the path.  So, if you don't know where it is to run it directly, then it is basically not installed as far as you are concerned because there is no way for you to use it.

Comment: I am making a pkg file which many different users will run on their systems. When the pkg file is run, it needs to run a script to detect whether node is installed on that system. The context in which the pkg file runs this script does not get the environment variables that a terminal gets passed. So in this context, node is not available even though node may be installed on the system.

Comment: Then, unless you want to search the entire hard drive or require the user to tell you where node.js is, there is no other way to see if node.js is there.  Either you check the path or you search the whole drive (or perhaps even all attached drives).  I'd suggest that you fix the original problem that the pkg environment is not getting any of the default environment.  That's where you really need to fix the problem.  If you want to know if `node xxx` will run, then you NEED to see the regular path environment so you can see if node is will run when given the right environment.

Comment: What about `/usr/bin/env node` rather than just `node`?

Comment: Nope, that also doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I am facing this issue outside the packages software as well. Another Node script which is the native host executable for a Chrome, works fine when the shebang has /usr/local/bin/node but doesnt start when the shebang is /usr/bin/env node. The strange thing is if I run the script from the command line, ie. "./index.js" then it works for both the shebangs, but when it is started by Chrome, the "/usr/bin/env node" shebang does not work while /usr/local/bin/node shebang does.

Comment: I came across this https://github.com/ghooks-org/ghooks/issues/30 and it seems due to security, /usr/bin/env is not allowed. I suspect that in the context that I am running my scripts, these variables are not allowed due to some sort of security policy on OSX, so I am not pursuing this further.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you:

```
whereis node | grep ' ' -ic
```

[image]