# /usr/bin/env node Shebang does not work on Mac OSX in certain cases

Tags: node.js, macos, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple node script which acts as the native host for a Chrome extension. When the shebang on this node script is

```
 #! /usr/local/bin/node
```

the script runs fine. I.e. the chrome extension is able to connect to the native host. But when I change the shebang to

```
  #! /usr/bin/env node
```

the chrome extension is unable to connect to the native host.

When I execute the script from the Terminal

```
  ./index.js
```

it executes perfectly normally in both the cases.

But when the Chrome extension tries to execute it, it fails in the second case.

Since I am developing this extension, it is not downloaded from the internet to have a quarantine xattr assigned to it.

I have [asked about a very similar problem I am facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742786/how-to-detect-whether-node-installed-when-node-is-not-available-in-environment) when trying to detect whether node is installed on a system when installing a package. There also if the full path of node is not given the script fails.

Why does the script which works in the Terminal not work when the Chrome extension tries to execute it?

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: When I run the script from the terminal, there is no error. When the script is run by the Chrome Extension, I only get to know that the extension was unable to connect to the script, which is what I can see in the extensions console. I dont know how to find the exact error why the script failed when run by extension. In the past, I have resolved such errors by running the script independently from the terminal and seeing the error it threw. No error is thrown now when run from the terminal.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that this probably happens due to some security policy on OSX which does not allow access to /usr/bin/env node when the script is running in a certain context. I cam e across this issue which talks about it a bit https://github.com/ghooks-org/ghooks/issues/30 . I am not searching for an answer further.